# Unix sed command

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file `foo.txt` containing

```
12345
123
123456
```

how do I make a `sed` command which puts the middle numbers in parenthesis?

so it would look like

```
1(234)5
1(2)3
1(2345)6
```

Comment: why on earth was this closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/./&(/;s/.$/)&/' foo.txt
```

Result

```
1(234)5
1(2)3
1(2345)6
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B.*\B/(&)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(.)(.*?)(.)$/$1($2)$3/g' your_file
```